# UITextView with text and images combined

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have this UIScrollView with images inside, all the images are 30x30. I also have a a UITextView under the scrollview. What I want to do is to edit the textview, write some text, than to drag the image to the textview, and it will be added after the text (like emoji).

How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `UIImageView` as a subView of `UITextView`.
such like, Create an imageView with image:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
[imageView setFrame:yourFrame];
[yourTextView addSubview:imageView];
```

And This is source code might be helpful in your case:
https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView
https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/imgglyph
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/secoretextview
http://ios-blog.co.uk/featured-posts/ios-5-rich-text-editing-series/

Comment: How would you preseve the textVIew contents in database?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, even I had this doubt, did you find any solution?